# How to connect Liferay Portal with mysql database using eclipse?

Tags: mysql, database-connection, liferay-6, liferay-ide

I have Liferay 6.2 and i want to connect with mysql database using eclipse IDE.How to connect them and what i have to use. Please give me any example for startup.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the below steps->

1. Create a new liferay server (Point it to the liferay portal).
2. Start the server.
3. When the server will start hit the
   localhost:8080.
4. A page will be displayed for the database
   configuration and user configuration.
5. provide the db name and
   usename and password.
6. Once you provide that, liferay will use
   that database.(Obviously that DB should be in your database)

Else you can create a portal-setup-wizard.properties file in \liferay-portal-6.2.0-ce-ga1 directory. Then add the following entries.

```
admin.email.from.name=Test Test
jdbc.default.password=root
liferay.home=D:/5555555/liferay-portal-6.2.0-ce-ga1
admin.email.from.address=test@liferay.com
jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.default.username=root
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/project_monitor_liferay?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false
setup.wizard.enabled=false
```

Else you can follow the below link

http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2013/12/liferay-62-portal-development.html

Here step by step process has been given. If you find it helpful then mark the above as an answer, so that it would be helpful for other persons also.

To use service builder in portlet you can go through the following links..
Learn how to create a portlet and integrate services in it.

```
https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/tree/master/portlets/sample-service-builder-portlet

http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/05/liferay-mvc-portlet-development-with.html

http://www.liferaysolution.com/2011/12/nice-video-tutorial-to-create-sample.html

http://innovationliferay.blogspot.in/p/service-builder-concept.html
```

Else you can download the liferay cookbook from
`http://www.mpowerglobal.com/download-cookbook`  This book contains all your query. You just need to dig into it and find.

Comment: Suppose i have created a login jsp in eclipse IDE and i want to store that user_name and password in mysql database. So, for that what i have to write in code to connect the database.Can you give me sample code for that to send the data and for retrieve the data from database.

Comment: If you will give me link for that or any documentation which have step by step solution in screen shot then that will more better for me.

Comment: I read this link liferaysawy.com its a good site and good explanation but i didn't find the database connection to liferay. Can you give any other link which explain about database connection like this link.

Comment: ok thanks for this. But i have connection with my database mysql but how to interact with them. I mean how to send a data to a particular table with using of eclipse. What i have to write in code to get data from any jsp page and send to database in particular table.

Comment: I already created a login page but i want connect with database table for that what i have to write a code like servlet code or spring  connection code or any other code in eclipse.Can you provide me any sample connection code with database.